# Is there a website that gathers all the economic indicators for all countries?

Tags: stock-markets, inflation

Right now, in order to get a sense of how the economy is doing, I'm simply reading news articles. I was wondering if there exists a website that gathers all that data in a very summarized fashion, to see GDP growth, inflation, stock market growth, unemployment rate for all the countries?

Comment: See the CIA Factbook: https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/

Comment: For the US, this data might keep you busy for awhile :->) . https://fred.stlouisfed.org/

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha is a good source for this type of information.

https://www.wolframalpha.com

[image]